# Create a 10^4 x 3 matrix the columns correspond to various functions

Tags: matlab

Create a *10^4*-by-*3* matrix where the rows correspond to `1:10^4` and the columns correspond to the functions `sin(x)`, `log(x)`, and `x^2`. Let the `(i,j)` entry be the value of the jth function evaluated on i.

Honestly, I don't really know how to create this matrix. My approach is to create a function using if condition.  For example,

```
if j<=10^4
    A(i,j) = sin(i)
elseif 10^4<j<=2*10^4
    A(i,j) = log(i)
elseif j>2*10^4
    A(i,j) = i^2.
```

Still, I don't know how to construct this function...

Comment: In MATLAB most of the mathematical functions accept a vector of arguments, and return the vector of values. So get the values for `sin`, `log` etc. on the same arguments `1:10^4` then combine the results.

Comment: Note that `10^4<j<=2*10^4` is not acceptable MATLAB syntax (and not accepted in any language that I can think of). You need to use the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really simple in MATLAB. If you're asking this question, then I *highly* recommend that you do a few basic MATLAB tutorials before you continue using the language.

Start off by just creating your `1:10^4` matrix which should be trivial since that is exactly the syntax, you just have to then transpose it:

```
t = (1:10^4)';
```

Now to get the `sin` of that just do `sin(t)` and to get a matrix with columns the way you want, just use [horizontal concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85019):

```
[sin(t), log(t), t.^2]
```

notice that is is `t.^2` and not `t^2` as `^` is actually a matrix operator whereas `.^` is an [element-wise operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).